# 'Grant' Word 403 Forbidden Issue in Ajax Form Submission

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-403, sql-grant

403 Forbidden Issue with `'grant' (example: grant@gmail.com)` word in email ID if we send an email to multiple email IDs. When we send mail to a single email `(including grant@gmail.com)` to anyone, it's working fine.

However, when we select multiple email addresses to send, it shows a 403 forbidden error if we include the email/word `'grant'`.

If we send emails to multiple addresses excluding `'grant@gmail.com'`, it works fine. Please check and let us know if there is any solution.

Here is my code:

```
function trpMailingSend() {
try {
    var e = $("#trpMailingSendForm").serializeArray(),
        t = new FormData;
    $.each(e, (function(e, n) {
        t.append(n.name, n.value)
    })), "" != $("#imageFileAdd").val() && (t.append("filePdf", $("#imageFileAdd")[0].files[0]), t.append("filePdfFile", $("#imageFileAdd")[0].files[0].name)), $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '#APPLICATION.navigation.getURL("mailing", "trpMailingSend")#',
        data: t,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: !1,
        cache: !1,
        processData: !1,
        error: function(e, t, n) {
            console.log(e), console.log(t), console.log(n), 403 === e.status ? (console.error("403 Forbidden: Access Denied"), "" !== e.responseText.trim() ? console.error("Response Text:", e.responseText) : console.error("Server did not provide additional information.")) : console.error("An error occurred:", n)
        },
        success: function(e) {
            if ("1" == e.status) {
                showPopOver("{{There was an error sending emails. Our development team has been notified of the problem and will contact you when it is fixed.}}", "sendEmailBtn", '<DIV CLASS="group-btn text-center" STYLE="min-width:81px;">\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<A CLASS="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ONCLICK="hidePopOver();">{{Ok}}</A>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</DIV>')
            } else messageSystem.showMessage("{{E-mail(s) were sent successfully!}}", "4", "", "goPage('mailing', 'trpMailingInfo', " + e.data + ", '?ret=<CFIF isDefined(trpId)>1<CFELSE>2</CFIF>');");
            console.log("test2"), console.log(e)
        }
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.error("An error occurred:", e)
 }
}
```

Comment: My code response:
POST https://portal.testpage.com/WX/apps/gxApps/mailing/trpMailingSend/ 403 (Forbidden)
error
403 Forbidden: Access Denied
Server did not provide additional information
We are trying to understand why there is an issue with the word 'grant' in the email ID when we select multiple emails.

Comment: Can you please format your code properly (read the guidelines...), and... other than that you're using a CFML variable in all that JavaScript, what's this got to do with either ColdFusion or Lucee? It's all client-side code...?

Comment: This code is related to client side, but we write this code on coldfusion lucce server

Comment: Are you using a WAF?  I recently encountered issues where an email starting with "curly" was considered a "Direct Unix Command Execution". We disabled that rule as it was causing to many false positives.

Comment: Yes but there's no CFML code in it, and the code is not being executed by the CFML server. Neither ColdFusion nor Lucee play any part in whatever problem is causing this. Untagging.